# RXjava onError on single does not work

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to invoke a http call using rx java.

it returns a Single  object.

This is the code:

```
 service.getEvent(eventId)
    .onErrorResumeNext(exception -> Single.error(exception))
    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error(throwable.getMessage())
    .subscribe(this::handleEvent)
```

The log is printing the log line expected in the "doOnError" but also prints the stacktrace:

```
 ERROR c.b.w.s.Service:161 - Error: Error, eventId: dummy-event

rx.exceptions.OnError
NotImplementedException: Error
    at rx.functions.Actions$NotImplemented.call(Actions.java:576)
    at rx.functions.Actions$NotImplemented.call(Actions.java:572)
    at rx.Single$11.onError(Single.java:1782)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleDoOnEvent$SingleDoOnEventSubscriber.onError(SingleDoOnEvent.java:76)
    at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:460)
    at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:456)
    at rx.Single.subscribe(Single.java:1967)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext$2.onError(SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext.java:69)
    at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:460)
    at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:456)
    at rx.Single.subscribe(Single.java:1967)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext.call(SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext.call(SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext.java:23)
    at rx.Single.subscribe(Single.java:1967)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleDoOnEvent.call(SingleDoOnEvent.java:40)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleDoOnEvent.call(SingleDoOnEvent.java:25)
    at rx.Single.subscribe(Single.java:1967)
    at rx.Single.subscribe(Single.java:1777)
    at rx.Single.subscribe(Single.java:1747)
```

How can I remove the stacktrace... also, I did implement onError?

Is single the right choise or should I use Observable?

Regards,
Ido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not implement the `onError` handler of the `subscribe` call. `doOnError` just peeks at the error but otherwise doesn't "consume" it. Move the `doOnError` argument as the second argument to `subscribe`:

```
service.getEvent(eventId)
.onErrorResumeNext(exception -> Single.error(exception))
.subscribe(this::handleEvent, throwable -> log.error(throwable.getMessage())
```

Also your `onErrorResumeNext` has no practical effect as it just replicates the same exception it received.

Comment: Thanks,  Should I use observalble here?

Comment: Do you plan to have multiple values with this setup in the future?

Comment: No.  Just api call. Get answer and return it